# Parse js - can't print records from relation data

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, relation

I would like to see the data from the class of game but users field is relation and gives me 
trouble

Game
object Id | createdAt | updatedAt | users (relation field type to User class)

User
object Id | createdAt | updatedAt | name

I would like to print the Game data:

`<td>`objectId`</td>`
`<td>`the names of the decimal like John Smith, John Smith ...`</td>`

Here is my code

```
var game = Parse.Object.extend("Game");
var query = new Parse.Query(game);  
query.include("users");
        $("#content").append("<table id='results'></table>");
        $("#results").text("");
        query.find({
          success: function(results) {
                var html = "<tr><th>createdAt</th><th>users</th></tr>";
                $("#results").append(html);
                for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                var object = results[i];
                var relation = object.relation('users');
                 relation.query().find({
                    success: function(toppings) {
                      // toppings is a list of toppings for this pizza
                      for(var j = 0; j < toppings.length; j++) {
                        alert(toppings[j].get("name"));
                      }
                    }
                  });
                var html = "<tr><td>" + object.createdAt + "</td><td></td></tr>";   
                $("#results").append(html);     
            }
          },
          error: function(error) {
            alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
          }
        }); 
}
```

please help

Comment: Relations don't support `include`

Comment: Ok, but do not know how to put the records from users field in the correct cell.